# Is Tortoise SVN the same as Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is Tortoise SVN affected by vulnerabilities affecting Subversion client as noted in the link below

https://subversion.apache.org/security/CVE-2017-9800-advisory.txt

Comment: Yes, TortoiseSVN is just user interface that runs command line svn commands underneath.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN is a GUI-based SVN client. SVN is one of its core components. The CVE that you are asking about was addressed in SVN 1.9.7 and TortoiseSVN 1.9.7. You can read about that on the main TortoiseSVN page at https://tortoisesvn.net/ and in Subversion 1.9.7 release announcement at https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-announce/201708.mbox/%3C2fefe468-7d41-11e7-aea1-9312c6089150%40apache.org%3E